# Angularjs - what is correct way to `push or unshift` a object to an array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am getting array values from the back-end. in this backend arrays, i am adding a new value, with some properties getting from one of the back-end array value. after I `unshift` this value I am consoling it. when I console it differs from what I see in `highlight` to `expanded` one.

here is the screenshot:

see the property `PhaseName` you will see `All` when that's expanded it shows nothing.

What is this problem is? how to solve?

[image]

here is my code :

```
$scope.project = project;

                var staticPhase = { //custom properties

                  "DisciplineId": "0",
                  "DisciplineName": "All",
                  "PhaseId": "0",
                  "PhaseName": "All"
                }

                var filterById = angular.copy( $filter('filter')($scope.project.ProjectSummaryFilter, { ProjectId : $scope.projectId })[0] );
//getting some of property from server object and assigning;-
                staticPhase.ProjectId = filterById.ProjectId;
                staticPhase.ProjectName = filterById.ProjectName;
                staticPhase.SubProjectId = filterById.SubProjectId;
                staticPhase.SubProjectName = filterById.SubProjectName;

                $scope.project.ProjectSummaryFilter.unshift(staticPhase);
```

Comment: Suggest you create demo that replicates this. Could just be a console quirk and you aren't showing where you log this to console. Note that console.log() does not create  snapshot copy

Comment: On side note...might want to look at `angular.extend()` to simplify merging objects

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. There's nothing special about using `push()` or `unshift()` w/respect to Angular. I guess your problem is that what you expect to see in the console doesn't match what you expect to see in the UI. But you don't show us the part where you log to the console nor do you show us the HTML for the UI. The statement about console.log() not creating a snapshot copy is probably your issue, but there's not enough info to say that w/certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use lodash with function  https://lodash.com/docs#remove

```
Or use can use the angular.forEach(function(val,index){
//then slice this here
});
```